# Do spells continue to use hand(s) on following rounds of combat?

Tags: arkham-horror

If I use a spell in combat (eg: Shriveling) on one turn of combat, and it succeeds, on a subsequent round of combat, does the spell still use up any "hands" for combat?

OR

After casting a spell, on a subsequent round of combat, is that hand(s) free to use other weapons/spells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the rulebook](http://new.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/Support/Arkham_Horror_Rules_Lo-Res.pdf), page 16:
*A spell or weapon that gives you a bonus (even one that says it lasts until the end of combat) only continues to give you the bonus while you devote the required number of hands to it. You can choose to switch weapons/spells in later combat rounds, but as soon as you “release” a spell or weapon, it stops working for you. Similarly, spells that are refreshed (such as at the beginning of each combat round in the final battle) cease to work and must be re-cast.*

Comment: I swear I could not find that in the rules.... thanks!!